# How to avoid if-else when getting values according to a table?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For example, I need to display different images according to boolean values `cond1` and `cond2` as follows:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">cond2</td>
    <tr>
        <td>cond1</td>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td>true</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td>img1.png</td>
                    <td>img2.png</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>true</td>
                    <td>img3.png</td>
                    <td>img4.png</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the codes looks like it:

```
var result;
if(!cond1 && !cond2){
  result="img1.png";
}else if(cond1 && !cond2){
  result="img3.png";
}else if(!cond1 && cond2){
  result="img2.png";
}else{
  result="img4.png";
}
```

Is there simpler way to avoid repeat `cond1` and `cond2` typing?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of the `img` using a simple formula.

Resolving that `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`(*using `+` operator, which parses into the `1` when true and `0` when false*), we can write a binary format of that condition and then parse it into the decimal.

```js
const cond1 = +true;
const cond2 = +false;

const str = cond1 + '' + cond2;

const imgNumber = parseInt(str, 2) + 1;
const result = `img${imgNumber}.png`;

console.log(result);
```

**Or as suggested in the comments, you can use shifting**

```js
const cond1 = true;
const cond2 = false;

const imgNumber = (cond1 << 1) + cond2 + 1;
const result = `img${imgNumber}.png`;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: No need to parse, it's a shift followed by addition.

Comment: The way you compute imgNumber. (cond1 << 1) + cond2

Comment: Thanks. Will add in the answer